# Magento - Resizing "More Views" on product page on configurable products

Tags: magento, thumbnails

I need help with resizing the "more views" on the product page when it is configurable product.

I resized the "more views" image from 56X56 t0 90X135 by changing the dimension on app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml.

When I first click the the product, the "more views" image dimension is correct, but when I click the option, the "more views" image goes back to 56X56.

I used "Template Path Hint", but it tells me the source code is from ...view/media.phtml, which I already modified.

How can I fix that?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out System->Configuration->Catalog->SMDesign ColorSwatch if there is anything interesting for you.

Moreover images are echoed in SMDesign_Colorswatch_GetController. So you can see where image sizes are come from.

Comment: Thank you.  I am still learning, so how did you find the image echo?  I tried firebug, but I could not find it.  But thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: SMDesign_Colorswatch_GetController lines 94 and 108. Where you have something like: ...'thumb'=>...